# How to load library only on one twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

We have a custom theme, `mytheme` where we have the following library for the `header-fix`. I have also added `{{ attach_library('mytheme/header-fix') }}` to only one twig template `block--myblock.html.twig` that is for my custom block `myblock`.

The goal is to only add the library to `myblock` when `myblock` is rendered on the page.

The problem we are having is that the library is being added to all pages even ones where the block is not present (loaded on the page). How can we load a single library only on one block and not all the twig templates?

**myblock configuration:**

1. restricted to only `Article` content type (so do not load on `basic` content type)

**block--myblock.html.twig**

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/header-fix') }}
<div>
  <p>Continually fashion turnkey sources without web-enabled alignments. Some more content.</p>
</div>
```

**mytheme.libraries.yml**

```
...
header-fix:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    /path/to/header-fix.js: { preproces: false, attributes: { defer: true } }
...
```

**mytheme.info.yml**

```
...
libraries:
  - mytheme/header-fix
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the reference from mytheme.info.yml.

That's adding it any time the theme is loaded (every page), whereas `attach_library` will add it only when that specific template is used.

You'll need to rebuild cache for the change to take effect.